# Entity-Framework Many-Many

Tags: entity-framework

So I have Work and Person models as follows:

```
public class Work{
  public int ID
  public string Name
  public virtual ICollection<Person> CurrentWorkers
  public virtual ICollection<Person> ProjectOwners
}

public class Person{
  public int ID
  public string UserID
  public virtual ICollection<Work> CurrentWork
}
```

Now when I go into the db to get my person (whom submitted the Work request):

```
//if exists
var person = db.Person.Find(id)
//else
Person person = new Person()
```

and try to assign an owner to the Work:

```
Work work = new Work()
work.ProjectOwners.Add(person) //NULL REF ERROR HERE
db.Work.Add(work)
```

I get a Null Reference error, which I guess is because work isn't in the db yet? So do I have to insert work and then go find it and then attach the Person? I don't quite understand how EF Many-Many works and links for additional reading into this would also be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

So the below works once but when I create a new `Work`, whatever was saved with any previous `work.ProjectOwners` gets wiped out. Any help with this, I understand WHY (because the FK column in `People` is being overwritten with the next `Work` PK) but I have no idea how to fix it?

```
work.ProjectOwners = new List<Person>();
```

Comment: I would initialize the `ProjectOwners` collection for the newly created `Work` before adding person: `work.ProjectOwners = new List<Person>();`

Comment: @Adolfo Well  I was doing that, but I just lose the reference any time a new Work gets created with the same person as an owner?

Comment: Here you'll find a very similar example to what you're trying to do: http://vincentlauzon.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/entity-framework-4-1-many-to-many-relationships-5/

Comment: @Adolfo Thanks but still can't assign in the way I want, currently I'm doing the reverse: person.OwnerOfWorks.Add(work) now, since that's the only thing that gives me sensible results...

Comment: Few questions: Are you using Entity Framework code-first? Could you show your model configuration? Are you creating a Relation table? e.g. WorkPerson. That will help experts better understand your problem. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

```
public class Work
{
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> CurrentWorkers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> ProjectOwners { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Work> CurrentWork { get; set; }
}

public class WorkContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Work> Works { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Work>().
          HasMany(w => w.ProjectOwners).
          WithMany(p => p.CurrentWork).
          Map(
           m =>
           {
               m.MapLeftKey("WorkId");
               m.MapRightKey("PersonId");
               m.ToTable("WorkPersons");
           });
    }
}
```

And here a simple test:

```
            var personJohn = new Person() {UserId = "John Doe"};
            var personJane = new Person() { UserId = "Jane Dee" };
            var work = new Work();
            work.ProjectOwners = new List<Person>();
            work.ProjectOwners.Add(personJohn);
            db.Works.Add(work);
            db.SaveChanges();
            work.ProjectOwners.Add(personJane);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

**Edit:**
Variation where you add a Person that already exists in the database (e.g. Jane):

```
            var john = new Person() {UserId = "JohnDoe"};
            var jane = new Person() { UserId = "JaneDee" };

            //Add Jane to DB
            db.Persons.Add(jane);
            db.SaveChanges();

            //Create new Work and initialize ProjectOwners collection
            var work = new Work();
            work.ProjectOwners = new List<Person>();

            //Add John (doesn't exist in DB yet)
            work.ProjectOwners.Add(john);
            db.Works.Add(work);
            db.SaveChanges();

            //Look for Jane in DB
            jane = db.Persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == "JaneDee");
            if (jane != null)
            {
                //Add existing Jane if found to work Project Owners
                work.ProjectOwners.Add(jane);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to write the above, very helpful. What I thought I was going to do with my models wasn't very good so I've rewritten most of it and have much less issues now. One question I have is how would you add an existing db row? Say Jane already exists in the database for your example, do: `var Jane = db.Person.Find(JaneID)` and then `work.ProjectOwners.Add(Jane)`?

Comment: Could I also ask for any more reading material that you might have about creating more complex models using EF?

Comment: There are good materials at the MSDN site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907 and I would also recommend watching Julie Lerman videos on channel 9: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Entity-Framework-Tips-and-Tricks

Comment: @Wurd take a look at my edited answer. I added an example on how to add a person that already exists in the db to your Work object.